# Converting html table to image with Java?

Tags: java, html, image

Given an Html file, which is a common html and contains a table, How can I identify the table and convert it to an image?

I know, there is a open tool, http://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/, but it convert the whole html file an Image file.

Comment: *"Given an Html file,.."* How about you give us an URL where we can see an example?  The devil is in the details.  The URL contains the answers to 1) Does the page actually have multiple tables, some for layout and others for data? 2) Is it valid HTML, or tag soup? 3) Do the data tables have id's? 4) Does the server permit such use? 5) Do the site hosts provide a better API for obtaining the tabular data?