# Convert Tables inside a HTML as Image

Tags: java, html

Is it possible to convert tables inside a HTML page as images? Yes, this is for a Newsletter. I have so far tried it with a HTML constructed with "div" elements, But they did not work out as expected in most of the browsers/email clients. Then I tried changing them all to basic HTML elements ("table","td","tr"). And yet it seems to be having a problem is some mail clients.

So I would like to try out the possibility of constructing the each table as a images. My code generator is a Java batch program. Data for the table is fetched from the Database and the Page is constructed, which I send it to users as an email. There was one post earlier with an similar topic [Converting html table to image with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628302/converting-html-table-to-image-with-java). But seems like there was no further updates from the questioner side.

The HTML page which I am trying to achieve would look something like :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/psc6Y.png

I am trying to make the ones in red as Images and make them as links. each one of the blocks will have a different URL. Inside each of the red blocks, there will be more than one html sub elements, like images,text..

Is this even possible?

Comment: Not sure about java but you can draw DOM to canvas in front end (js). Might be useful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Comment: Could you use the Java-Javascript bridge to run the DOM to canvas?

Comment: I believe java script's will filtered out in most of the current email clients due to security reasons.